# Is there anyway to standardize page length in iBooks?

Tags: macos, ios, books

I've been using iBooks lately to read a book, and I'd like to be able to set a page goal for myself, like I want to read 20 pages per day.  However, since page sizes differ between iPhone, Mac full screen, and Mac in an arbitrarily sized window, there's not really any standardized concept of a page of a book, which I find pretty frustrating.

Does anybody have any suggestions for how to circumvent this problem? I'm not *specifically* asking for ways of keeping the same page size everywhere (though that would be one possible solution), but rather, I'm looking for some way I can implement these reading goals for myself and know whether I'm completing them.

I suppose one thing I could do is just set goals based on percentages (i.e. I will read 5% per day), but I don't love this.

Thanks!